# how to dynamically change bootstrap modal data-target click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a website calendar which acts similar to a reservation request.
I had this working in Bootstrap 2x but have converted the app to 3.0.  Everything seems to be working, but I am trying to figure out how to dynamically change the data-target.

If a date is available, a day in the calendar may look like this:

```
<div id="20140226" data-id="20140226" class="NotRequested calDay" data-target="#modalDialog1" data-toggle="modal">26</div>
```

I have a show event that pulls the id of the day div and sets the id of the request div which works fine.

```
$('#modalDialog1').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { 
    $(e.target).data("id", $(e.relatedTarget).data("id"));
}
```

In this modal, a button sends a request for the date, and if successful, swaps the class of the div to show that the date has been requested.

Here's my issue:
In Bootstrap 2x I would unbind the click event, and rebind to a new click event.

In Bootstrap 3x I am trying to change the data target.

```
dateElement.data("target", "#modalDialog2");
```

When I click on this date again, I get the initial Request dialog "#modalDialog1" instead of #modalDialog2

I have also tried keeping the bind/unbind code, however, it looks like I will need to remove the modal data-toggle as now it's showing both dialogs after requesting a date.

I'm obviously missing something.

How can I dynamically change the data-target so that it will call the 2nd dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, so I hope this is all correct.

I believe I have solved this by getting the date element above by getting the id from the request modalDialog1.

If the request was successful, then the css and click event is altered.

```
var dateElement = $("#" + $("#modalDialog1").data("id"));
dateElement.removeClass("NotReceived");
dateElement.unbind('click');
```

Then setting the new css and target

```
dateElement.addClass("Requested");
dateElement("target", "#modalDialog2");
```

Then binding the click event to the a new function to display dialog2

```
dateElement.bind('click', PromptDialog2Function);
```

Comment: Hey mate, I was facing a similar problem like this. Your solution didn't fully help me. Can you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844768/dynamic-data-target-bootstrap-modal  issue? It will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my simple code below, the dropdownlist determines which dialog will be shown

```
<select onchange="$('#btn').data('target', this.value)">
<option value="#dlg1">Dialog 1</option>
<option value="#dlg2">Dialog 2</option>
</select>
<button id="btn" data-target="#dlg1" onclick="$($(this).data('target')).modal('show');">
    Show Dialog
</button>
```