# dynamic data target bootstrap modal -Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bunch of posts to show on a page. After clicking to read more, a bootstrap modal will come where the post will be showed. Also I am using django.

The thing is that I want to iterate through my queryset of all posts with a for loop.

My html looks like:

```
 {% for post in posts %}

   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="post1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-body">         

             <!-- Button trigger modal -->

             <p> {{ post.content|truncatewords:10 }}  
             <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#post1">Post 1</a></p>       

           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

As you can see, here, in the trigger for showing the modal, `data-target="#post1"` is there and in the modal, there is also `id="post1"`.

Now it's okay for one modal. But I have like 10-12  blog posts. So I can't hardcode each of it's data-target. So what can I do? I don't know javascript, so a complete bootstrap solution maybe helpful. Nevertheless any solution or idea what can I do?
Like `post1` will get the `id1` and then `post2` should get the `id2`.

So can you please help me with this or give any other solution? It will be extremely helpful.
I have tried this post: [how to dynamically change bootstrap modal data-target click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444595/how-to-dynamically-change-bootstrap-modal-data-target-click) but that didn't help.

Comment: You could try this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

If that doesn't work you'd be better either finding help from someone who knows how to dynamically program it or just code loads of individual static modals into your page.

Comment: I actually got this code from the link you showed and so obviously it didn't work. And coding static modals isn't feasible for me because of the huge amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it was fairly simple, what I needed to do was to change the `modal-target` to `#modal{{post.id}}"` and the `id` of modal to `modal{{post.id}}` and voila!